# How can I find the order of $\overline {15}+ <\overline 4>$ in $\Bbb Z_{45}/<\overline 4>$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

find the order of $\overline {15}+ <\overline 4>$ in $\Bbb Z_{45}/<\overline 4>$

how can I start? is it $\Bbb Z_{45}/<\overline 4>\cong \Bbb Z$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$<\overline 4> = \{ \dots, -4, 0, 4, 8, 12, \dots\}$$

so each of the numbers in that set is zero in $\mathbb Z_{45}/<\overline 4>$, also m multiples of 45 are zero.

Therefore every number that can be written as $4x + 45y$ is zero, but every integer can be since $(4,45) = 1$.

That tells you that $\mathbb Z_{45}/<\overline 4>$ is the trivial group and 15 has order 1 in it.

Answer (score 0):

As $\;\bar 4$ is a unit in $\mathbf Z/45\mathbf Z$, the subgroup generated by $\bar 4$ is $\mathbf Z/45\mathbf Z$, hence $(\mathbf Z/45\mathbf Z)/\overline4(\mathbf Z/45\mathbf Z)=0$. So the order is $1$.

Comment: since it is trivial and has order 1 shouldnt order of every element that inside divide 1?

Comment: Yes, for any $ \bar a\in \mathbf Z/45\mathbf Z$, it wll be the same.

Answer (score 0):

$\bar{4}$ multiples span the entire group $\Bbb Z_{45}$: for example $12 \cdot \bar{4} = \bar{48} = \bar{3}$. Hence $<\bar{4}> = \Bbb Z_{45}$ and $\Bbb Z_{45}/<\bar{4}>$ is the trivial group with one element. Hence the order of any of its elements is 1